# Question on joins with multi tables

Tags: sql-server, join, query

I have 4 tables ( 1 to many table relation) as shown
Main , Worker , Location  and MiddleName Table

[image]

Any suggestions on how to get the result. I tried joins and it never worked.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots.  Instead, construct your question using the directions in [mcve].

Comment: Also, please take the [tour], and browse through the [help] if you have questions around how to use the site.

Comment: There are many ways to get that final result, but what is the logic behind it? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to print the firstname, workerId, location and middle name of the person based on the ID. Using Joins gives me both right and incorrect data so wasnt sure how to address it.

Comment: Who gave you the result you are trying to get? Why does worker id 123 correlate to Asia? What are the relational requirements?

Comment: @CalebCarl I am just trying to mock data here, sorry if the values does not make sense. Technically, I have 1 to many relation tables. The Id is the primary key on the Main table. While the other tables does not have any primary key meaning there could be multiple rows for the given Id (primary key) value referred from the main table.

Comment: I posted an answer - I'll edit it based on which answer you were actually going for.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks @Caleb Carl . May I know the reason of using the ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn ?

Comment: Which solution worked? The first or the second?

Comment: second solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #main
(
    ID INT
  , firstName VARCHAR(12)
);

CREATE TABLE #worker
(
    ID INT
  , WorkerID INT
);

CREATE TABLE #location
(
    ID INT
  , Location VARCHAR(12)
);

CREATE TABLE #middlename
(
    ID INT
  , MiddleName VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO #main
VALUES
(1, 'Jim')
, (2, 'John');

INSERT INTO #worker
VALUES
(1, 123)
, (1, 2345)
, (2, 4534);

INSERT INTO #location
VALUES
(1, 'Asia')
, (1, 'America')
, (1, 'Africa');

INSERT INTO #middlename
VALUES
(2, 'Jack');
```

If you are just trying to join the tables based on what you said in the comments, do this -

```
SELECT m.ID
     , m.firstName
     , w.WorkerID
     , l.Location
     , mn.MiddleName
FROM #main AS m
    LEFT JOIN #worker AS w
        ON w.ID = m.ID
    LEFT JOIN #location AS l
        ON l.ID = m.ID
    LEFT JOIN #middlename AS mn
        ON mn.ID = m.ID
WHERE m.ID = 1;
```

| ID | firstName | WorkerID | Location | MiddleName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim | 123 | Asia | *null* |
| 1 | Jim | 123 | America | *null* |
| 1 | Jim | 123 | Africa | *null* |
| 1 | Jim | 2345 | Asia | *null* |
| 1 | Jim | 2345 | America | *null* |
| 1 | Jim | 2345 | Africa | *null* |

But if you are trying to get that weird result, it's junk, but do this -

```
SELECT base.ID
     , base.firstName
     , IIF(base.ID = w.ID, w.WorkerID, NULL) AS WorkerID
     , base.Location
     , base.MiddleName
FROM
(
    SELECT m.ID
         , m.firstName
         , l.Location
         , mn.MiddleName
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM #main AS m
        LEFT JOIN #location AS l
            ON l.ID = m.ID
        LEFT JOIN #middlename AS mn
            ON mn.ID = m.ID
    WHERE m.ID = 1
) AS base
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID
             , WorkerID
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
        FROM #worker
    ) AS w
        ON base.rn = w.rn;
```

| ID | firstName | WorkerID | Location | MiddleName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim | 123 | Asia | *null* |
| 1 | Jim | 2345 | America | *null* |
| 1 | Jim | *null* | Africa | *null* |

[demo DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QG7jCi7T)